# How do you match multiple lines with dot (DOTALL) in eclipse find regex

Tags: regex, eclipse, multiline

I would like to convert this:

```
  def getEmployeeReminders(employeeId: Int, page: Option[Int], pageSize: Option[Int], js_callback: Option[String]) = Action {
      val reminders = Reminder.listForOne(employeeId, page, pageSize)
      getResponse(reminders, js_callback)
    }
```

to this:

```
  def getEmployeeReminders(employeeId: Int, page: Option[Int], pageSize: Option[Int], js_callback: Option[String]) =
    Restrict(companyAdmin, new MyDeadboltHandler) {
      Action {
        val reminders = Reminder.listForOne(employeeId, page, pageSize)
        getResponse(reminders, js_callback)
      }
    }
```

Multiple times in eclipse scala editor.

How do you match multiple lines with a '.*' ?
Also, how do you inject newline into replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `(?s)` inline mode modifier which will force the dot `.` to match newline characters as well. In your answer, you are using a negated character class so there is no need to use this modifier, and simply use `\n`

```
Find:    = (Action[^}]*})
Replace: = \n    Restrict(companyAdmin, new MyDeadboltHandler) {\n     \1}
```

Using the dot `.` instead:

```
Find:    (?s)= (Action.*?})
Replace: = \n    Restrict(companyAdmin, new MyDeadboltHandler) {\n     \1}
```

Comment: I tried using dot rather than negated character class.  This did NOT match my intended block, however. Rather, it matched much more than intended since it defaulted to 'greedy' matching.  I suspected there is a way to use dot AND specify non-greedy, but I was in a hurry.

Comment: Following the `.*` with `?` will make it non-greedy.

Answer (score 2):

place the following at very beginning of the 'find' expression:  (?s)
also note, we use \R to insert a newline:

Example:

```
find:      (?s)= (Action[^}]*})
replace:   = \R    Restrict(companyAdmin, new MyDeadboltHandler) {\R     \1}
```

This takes something like this:

```
  def getEmployeeReminders(employeeId: Int, page: Option[Int], pageSize: Option[Int], js_callback: Option[String]) = Action {
      val reminders = Reminder.listForOne(employeeId, page, pageSize)
      getResponse(reminders, js_callback)
    }
```

And replaces it with this:

```
  def getEmployeeReminders(employeeId: Int, page: Option[Int], pageSize: Option[Int], js_callback: Option[String]) =
    Restrict(companyAdmin, new MyDeadboltHandler) {
      Action {
        val reminders = Reminder.listForOne(employeeId, page, pageSize)
        getResponse(reminders, js_callback)
      }
    }
```