# Search for multiple keywords appearing on multiple lines in multiple files in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, ide

How can I find BOTH keywords `keyword0` `keyword1` using the File Search in the Eclipse IDE? These keywords appear on multiple lines in some of the files. I have tried to use Eclipse's File Search Regular Expression search by using the format:

```
(keyword0.*keyword1|keyword1.*keyword0)
```

However this doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596950/how-do-you-match-multiple-lines-with-dot-dotall-in-eclipse-find-regex

Comment: This didn't solve the problem.   (i.e., placing a question mark at the end of the wildcard:  .*?  did not result in it finding both keywords)

Comment: Use the dotall modifier `(?s)(keyword0.*keyword1|keyword1.*keyword0)`

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the package in Package Explorer, press Ctrl-H and click on 'Selected Resources'.